# How to keep TabHost at portrait orientation and listen for configChanges (orientation)

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

Could you advise how to keep TabHost with all tabs at portrait screen orientation and at the same time listen for configChanges = orientation? I am going to show another activity when orientation is changed.

Seems to me configChanges (orientation) event does not fire when screenOrientation is set to portrait mode.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the orientation of your TabHost to portrait? If so, you actually want "sensorPortrait" so that sensing continues. Keep your configChanges:orientation so you can handle changes yourself.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) for more info.